# Mongodb - Security weakness while using --authenticationDatabase admin?

Tags: mongodb, security, nosql

I was trying to create a new Mongodb instance based on my old Mongo Database. In my current DB I have an user and password configured. So, I can access my database using:

```
$ mongo --host $MONGO_HOST -u $MONGO_USER -p $MONGO_PASSWORD --authenticationDatabase admin
```

This works perfectly. But accidentally, I typed:

```
$ mongo --host $MONGO_HOST --authenticationDatabase admin
```

And this is when the problem came in! The MongoDatabase authorized my connection for the database!  The `security.authorization` is set as true in my `mongod.conf`. Is this a weakness in MongoDB? Is there any method to always force the authentication?

EDIT 1: Current configuration for mongo:

```
{
    "config" : "/etc/mongod.conf",
    "net" : {
        "bindIp" : "0.0.0.0",
        "port" : 27017
    },
    "security" : {
        "authorization" : "enabled"
    },
    "storage" : {
        "dbPath" : "/var/lib/mongodb",
        "journal" : {
            "enabled" : true
        }
    },
    "systemLog" : {
        "destination" : "file",
        "logAppend" : true,
        "path" : "/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log",
        "quiet" : true
    }
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you may have configured users but not enabled access control. Please edit your question to include the output of `db.serverCmdLineOpts().parsed` from the `mongo` shell.

Comment: @Stennie question updated

Comment: What is the output of `db.getSiblingDB('admin').getUsers().length` and `db.version()`?

Comment: @Stennie `1` and `4.0.9`

Comment: OK, so it appears you have access control enabled and at least one user configured. When you login using `mongo --authenticationDatabase admin` what happens if you run commands like `show dbs` or `show collections`?

Comment: Ok,forget it. It shows nothing.

Comment: If you connect but haven't authenticated, you should get an error like `not authorized on dbname to execute command`. Is that what you mean by showing nothing?

Comment: No, it shows exactly nothing.